# WebApi CORs - Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on request error

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

**Question Background:**

This seems to be a common issue and one I have fallen foul of.

I have a standard WebApi currently hosted in Azure and a calling AngularJS app that calls an end point on said WebApi.

The AngularJS app URL calling to the WebApi is:

```
http://siteang.azurewebsites.net
```

And the WebApi address is:

```
https://site.azurewebsites.net
```

**I want to ensure that only my app at `http://siteang.azurewebsites.net` is capable of accessing the WebApi at `https://site.azurewebsites.net`**

**The Issue:**

I am receiving the following error on the submitting form of my AngularJS app to the WebApi service.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://site.azurewebsites.net/api/ShoppingComparison/GetC…itemIndex=Baby&itemtosearch=baby&lowToHigh=false&maxPrice=50000&minPrice=0.

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://siteang.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

**The Code:**

The following is the $http request to the WebApi service.

Note that the header property of the call has been set with the address of the AngularJS site.

```
   loadSearchList: function (itemToSearch, itemIndex, countryCode) {
        self.itemToSearch = itemToSearch;
        self.itemCatagory = itemIndex;
        self.country = countryCode;

        self.searchList = [];

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://site.azurewebsites.net/api/ShoppingComparison/GetComparisons',
            params: {
                itemtosearch: itemToSearch,
                itemIndex: itemIndex,
                countryCode: countryCode,
                maxPrice: '50000',
                minPrice: '0',
                highToLow: true,
                lowToHigh: false,
                amazonEbay: true,
                amazonOnly: false,
                ebayOnly: false
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://siteang.azurewebsites.net',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'
            }
        }).success(function (data) {

            //Success Handler.

        }).error(function (data) {

            //Error Handler.

        });

    }
```

The following is the WebApi Controller that is being calling by the AngularJS app. Note that the header has been set to accept the `http://siteang.azurewebsites.net` site that is making the call:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://siteang.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public ViewItemModel GetComparisons([FromUri] ComparisonRequestModel comparisonModel)
    {
        return _callAndSearchApis.SearchApis(comparisonModel);
    }
```

Any help in determing why this request is being rejected by the WebApi controller will be much appreciated.

Comment: DOes it has Authentication ?

Comment: What browsers did you test? There are some browsers not supporting CORS: http://caniuse.com/cors

Comment: did you call  `config.EnableCors();`?

Comment: another thing you can try is removing `headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://siteang.azurewebsites.net',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'
            }` so the browser does not need to send preflight request

Comment: @KhanhTO Thanks for your reply. I did as you said and removed the headers JSON and it did indeed mean I could only request from one specific web app. But, If I put the WebApi URL into POSTMAN it will still allow access to the API and return the results, why is this?

Comment: @user1352057 Have you tried setting CORS in Azure portal? For this, you need to go to latest version of Azure portal, select your web-api (Azure App service), on right side, select API - CORS, add * or required whitelist url.

Comment: @user1352057: it still allows POSTMAN to access => I think POSTMAN does not implement CORS specification, so it just ignores the headers from the server

Comment: Try adding `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "http://siteang.azurewebsites.net", methods: "*")]` instead of `[EnableCors(origins: "http://siteang.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CORS request headers are *imposed* by the browser automatically for cross origin requests. There's no way to change them. In fact, CORS would be pointless if the client could set CORS allow headers.

The error your seeing is that your server didn't include the required  `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers in the *response* during a preflight request. Preflight requests (OPTIONS) are performed when the client is doing something other than a simple GET request, including when custom request headers are added (which your Allow headers are).

To be fair, your confusion is probably not helped by the error ("... not present on the *requested* resource").

I'd recommend removing the CORS headers from the request and trying it again. If it still fails, capture the request using an HTTP proxy like Fiddler and update your question with the CORS headers in the preflight request and response.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are mixing protocols here http and https. Check the url you are requesting is having https. Please make sure that is correct first. Then you need to figure out if the server is rejecting and what it is doing. There are number of resources for Enabling cors. Even Stackoverflow has numberof threads.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Enabling+Cors+WebApi

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Edited Answer:
 Sometimes your IIS would interfere with the preflight OPTIONS requests. Try doing something like this in your web.config and see if it works.

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-webapi-cors

Comment: HTTP-to-HTTPS cross origin requests are supported by CORS. It's only XDomain, used by IE8/9, that doesn't support it.

Comment: I wasnt talking about http-to-https requests, I didn't notice the headers being set, and thought there was difference int the allowed origin being set versus the header being sent by the request. Anyhow, that is not the issue here.

Comment: Ah I get you. Thanks for clarifiying.

Comment: Thanks to you :) ...it helped me revisit the issue and realize it is not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that your server is returning a 500 error, and that it is that 500 error response itself that does not have CORS headers enabled on it. To confirm, I would encourage you to use a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test your API directly and ensure that the actual API request completes successfully.

Separately, you can then consider whether you want various server status response messages (for 500, 403, 302, etc) to have CORS headers included with them.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108413/cors-and-internal-server-error-responses