# FastAPI CORS, wildcard in allow origins not working

Tags: python, next.js, cors, fastapi, middleware

Simplified versions of my code, using two approaches.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

middleware = [
    Middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=["*"],
        allow_credentials=False,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )
]

app = FastAPI(middleware=middleware)
```

From the documentation.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

CORS always fails. It gives me the `CORS Missing Allow Origin` error (or just a general `CORS` error. I have double, triple, and centuple checked the headers. The request always sends an origin and FastAPI never responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I feel as if I am missing something incredibly simple here. My front end uses NextJS, and I am caching most of my requests with Redis. The entire network is under Docker and I have tried CORS from both `localhost` and outside proxies. I don't think any of that info is pertinent, but you never know.

Comment: Do you see the preflight calls?  Is your API call succeeding otherwise?  If it would return a non-200 you can have issue.

Comment: Does it work if you specify origins explicitly? e.g. `allow_origins=["localhost"]`

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407352/17865804), as well as all the relevant answers povided at the end of it, helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I was using Github Codespaces, and the CORS was being messed up. Switching to an entirely local build did the trick.