# Cant fetch data from my backend because of CORS same origin policy

Tags: sqlalchemy, cors, fastapi, fastapi-middleware

Im trying to fetch data from my backend but I keep getting this error

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/products. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

I am using fastapi and my cors configuration looks ok

this is how I set up my CORS in my routing file

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from db import local_session
from typing import List
import models
from schemas import Product

app = FastAPI()

origin = ['*']

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origin,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the terminal? If the endpoint crashes, the CIRS header will not be set, making it look like a CORS error in the browser.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407352/17865804) helpful.