# CORS Issue in FastApi + Graphene: No Response Beyond GQL Playground

Tags: python, graphql, cors, fastapi, graphene-python

#### CORS Issue in Semi-Production Environment with FastApi + Graphene

##### Problem Description:

I'm facing an issue with configuring CORS on a FastApi server using Graphene (Starlette). In a semi-production environment, when the server is hosted by uvicorn/gunicorn and accessible from the entire local network (using the `--host 0.0.0.0` flag), I don't receive any response other than a CORS error. Even Postman (from the local network via VPN) is unable to fetch the schema from the server.

##### Previous Attempts to Solve the Issue:

1. Setting `allow_orgins` to `"*"` - no effect, and according to the documentation, this option prohibits sending credentials, tokens, etc.
2. Setting `allow_origins` to the computer's address with Postman - no effect.
3. Setting `allow_origins` to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` - no effect.
4. Setting `allow_origins` to `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` - no effect.
5. Setting `allow_origins` to `http://localhost:80` or `http://127.0.0.1:80` - no effect.

##### Specifications:

- Python 3.11
- Ubuntu 23.04 Server
- Hosting by uvicorn and gunicorn
- Framework: FastAPI
- Added middleware for CORS handling:

  ```py
  app.add_middleware(
      CORSMiddleware,
      allow_origins=["http://localhost:5173"],  # Specify the exact source
      allow_credentials=True,
      allow_methods=["*", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST"],
      allow_headers=["*"],
      expose_headers=["*"],
  )
  ```
- GraphQL schema available at `/graphql`.

##### Additional Information:

- Frontend is on the same server as the backend.
- In Postman and the frontend, I provide the server's local IP:8000.
- Port 8000 is open in ufw, and the backend is running on it.

I kindly request assistance in resolving this CORS issue. Thank you in advance for any suggestions and guidance!

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407352/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77032415/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804)