# How do I protect my FastAPI REST-ful services by making sure request are coming from only a certain domain (front-end application)?

Tags: python, angular, rest, cors, fastapi

I have an application stack as follows.

- Backend: FastAPI, REST-ful service; eg r.domain.com
- Frontend: Angular 17 application; eg w.domain.com

On the backend, I want to ensure that a response is generated only for requests coming from the frontend application (eg w.domain.com). My current strategy is to look at the incoming request headers (eg referrer, host, user-agent) and reject. I have something like the following defined (middleware).

```py
if headers_not_ok(request):
    return JSONResponse(content='BAD_REQUEST', status_code=403)
```

This approach, I found, is not strong enough to protect or only allow processing for requests that comes from the frontend app. In Google Chrome, you can inspect the network and copy the request as a curl command, and executing such copied command will bypass checking based on headers (since the correct headers are declared as a part of the request).

I thought maybe all backends are susceptible to this problem, but apparently not. For example, if I am on Facebook and I copy the request to a curl command and execute it in the terminal, Facebook's backend logic is able to detect that I'm not logged in. I wonder how are they achieving this feat and how I can mimic the same for my situation.

In my situation, there is no login yet. It is opened to the public. However, the main goal is to not respond to any request that is not coming from the frontend application.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241648/17865804) (under **Important Note** section). You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804) helpful as well.

Comment: It should also be noted that, by default, for security reasons, browsers restrict [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) HTTP requests initiated **from scripts**. For example, `fetch()` follows the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: To allow a server to indicate that any [origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) **other than its own** from which a browser should permit loading resources, one has to [enable CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) on their server. Further related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77032415/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407352/17865804)