# I'm using React and FastAPI and am unable to achieve successful communication between the two for what I assume to be a CORS related issue

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, fastapi

This is my react file:

```
import "../styles/login.css"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react"


function Login({ setAuthToken }) {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [err, setErr] = useState(null);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleLogin =  () => {
        console.log("hello")
        try {
            console.log(1)
            // setIsLoading(true)
            // console.log(2)
            const payload = {
                "email": document.getElementById("login_email_input").value,
                "password": document.getElementById("login_password_input").value
            }
            console.log(payload)
            const response = fetch(
                process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_DOMAIN + "/users/login",
                {
                    mode: "cors",
                    method: "POST",
                    body: payload,
                    headers: {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Accept": "application/json"
                    }
                }
            );
            const data = response.json();
            console.log(response)
            console.log(3)
            // setAuthToken(true)
            // console.log(4)
            // navigate("/sets")
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(5)
            console.log(err.response.data)
            setErr(err.response.data);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }

    return (
        <form className="LoginForm" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <p>Welcome back!</p>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input className="Input" required placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email" id="login_email_input"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input className="Input" required placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" name="password" id="login_password_input"/>
            </div>
            <button className="SubmitButton" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </form>
    )
}


export default Login;
```

This is my FastAPI application definition:

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=[
        "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
        "http://localhost:3000"
    ],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["*"]
)
app.include_router(users_router, prefix="/users")
```

This is my login function:

```
def login_user(auth_obj: AuthOM):
    record = mysql_get_user_by_email(auth_obj.email)
    if record is None:
        raise HTTPExceptionNative(404, "User not found")
    password_hash = record[2]
    is_congruent = _verify_password_against_hash(auth_obj.password, password_hash)
    if not is_congruent:
        raise HTTPExceptionNative(401, "Invalid password")
```

And this is my object definition for the payload:

```
class AuthOM(BaseModel):
    email: str
    password: str
```

I am receiving a 422 with no payload on the dev console in google:
[response payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzNM6.png)

But receive a body with postman when intentionally malforming the request (the function works):
[body (confid params excluded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wTTj.png)

These are the fastapi logs: [fastapi_logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh3Ck.png)

I have tried unserialized and serialized bodies, modifying functions to be async (as I am largely unfamiliar with JS so not certain this is unrelated), and modifying the shown headers in every possible combination and it still does not work.

Serializing with JSON.serialize causes this: [cancelled_request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj2Mp.png)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, it has absolutely no business being part of your _request_ headers. // Does that 422 response cause any relevant error log entries on the server side?

Comment: 422 is thrown automatically by fastapi when body fails to match shape/type of specified object associated with the function (i.e. AuthOM). It is thrown before it calls the login_user func

Comment: 422 is not related to CORS. There's something expected missing in your request, and the body of the 422 error will tell you what parts of the request failed validation. Are you missing `JSON.stringify(payload)` before sending JSON data in your body? (it doesn't seem like you're converting your content to JSON anywhere).

Comment: @NoviSandlin In addition to the links provided in the banner above, please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427592/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407352/17865804)